# Why UIActionSheet caches delegate selectors?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, uiactionsheet

I recently found that `UIActionSheet` actually caches its available delegate selectors before it presents.

Why not determine whether the delegate responds to a certain selector when it really needs to know? Is `[delegate respondsToSelector:@selector()]` really slow to perform? Should we use this kind of design pattern in our own code? Any ideas would be appreciated!

The flags struct in UIActionSheet.h is as follows:

```
struct {
    unsigned int numberOfRows:7;
    unsigned int delegateAlertSheetButtonClicked:1;
    unsigned int delegateDidPresentAlertSheet:1;
    unsigned int delegateDidDismissAlertSheet:1;
    unsigned int hideButtonBar:1;
    unsigned int alertStyle:3;
    unsigned int dontDimBackground:1;
    unsigned int dismissSuspended:1;
    unsigned int dontBlockInteraction:1;
    unsigned int sheetWasPoppedUp:1;
    unsigned int sheetWasShown:1;
    unsigned int animating:1;
    unsigned int hideWhenDoneAnimating:1;
    unsigned int layoutWhenDoneAnimating:1;
    unsigned int titleMaxLineCount:2;
    unsigned int bodyTextMaxLineCount:3;
    unsigned int runsModal:1;
    unsigned int runningModal:1;
    unsigned int addedTextView:1;
    unsigned int addedTableShadows:1;
    unsigned int showOverSBAlerts:1;

    unsigned int showMinTableContent:1;
    unsigned int bodyTextTruncated:1;
    unsigned int orientation:3;
    unsigned int popupFromPoint:1;
    unsigned int inPopover:1;
    unsigned int delegateBodyTextAlignment:1;
    unsigned int delegateClickedButtonAtIndex:1;
    unsigned int delegateClickedButtonAtIndex2:1;
    unsigned int delegateCancel:1;
    unsigned int delegateCancel2:1;
    unsigned int delegateWillPresent:1;
    unsigned int delegateWillPresent2:1;
    unsigned int delegateDidPresent:1;
    unsigned int delegateDidPresent2:1;
    unsigned int delegateWillDismiss:1;
    unsigned int delegateWillDismiss2:1;
    unsigned int delegateDidDismiss:1;
    unsigned int delegateDidDismiss2:1;
    unsigned int dontCallDismissDelegate:1;
    unsigned int useAutomaticKB:1;
    unsigned int twoColumnsLayoutMode:7; // one column || even width (leaves empty space) || first button wider || last button wider
    unsigned int threeColumnsLayoutMode:7; // one column || even width (leaves empty space) || first button wider || last button wider
    unsigned int shouldHandleFirstKeyUpEvent:1; // when presenting with hardware KB we have to handle the first key up event we get so we don't end up repeating the last key
    unsigned int cancelWhenDoneAnimating:1;
    unsigned int useThreePartButtons:1; // phone numbers layout
    unsigned int useTwoPartButtons:1; // doc interaction layout
    unsigned int displaySelectedButtonGlyph:1;
    int indexOfSelectedButton:7; // default -1 (no checkmark) otherwise will display a checkbox (this for the airtunes action sheet)
    unsigned int useCustomSelectedButtonGlyph:1;
} _modalViewFlags;
```

Comment: What have the flags to do with selector caching?

Comment: If you override `respondsToSelector:` in your `UIActionSheet` delegate to `NSLog` the message, you will find that the action sheet sends the delegate a bunch of `respondsToSelector:` messages when you set the delegate on the sheet.  Presumably it uses the flags to record which `respondsToSelector:` messages returned YES.  [I've noticed this myself.](https://github.com/mayoff/BlockModals)  It really seems wasteful to me in this case, but perhaps Apple has some standard template for doing this on all of their classes that use delegates.  `UIAlertView` does the same thing.